# Where is Process on Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, process

I am trying to create a process in a Windows Phone 7 project. So I have a line:

```
Process process;
```

However, Visual Studio can't find the assembly for Process. I have included using System.Diagnostics, but the namespace doesn't have Process. I suspect this class is not supported on phone 7......

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? as you cant run an external processes in an application on WP7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't launch or control other processes from your Windows Phone 7 application.

Comment: Using the Launchers and Choosers you **are** launching and controlling other processes. But that's just a nit-pick: outside of these carefully regimented scenarios, you can't launch or control any other arbitrary process on the system.